# What is the difference between service provier and resident service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I can not understand the difference between service provier and resident service provider.I understand like following.

When i want provisioing and service provider using HTTP Basic Authentication and SCIM API, IS server have to configure resident service provider's provisioning configuration. Is it right?

When i want provisioing and service provider using OAuth Authentication Authentication and SCIM API, IS server doesn't need to to configure resident service provider, just required service provider's provisioning configuration. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your understanding is correct. WSO2IS normally can mediate authentication requests between SPs and IDPs. At the same time, the Identity Server itself can act as a service provider and an identity provider. When it acts as a service provider it is known as the `Resident Service Provider`.  When you are provisioning users using SCIM, WSO2IS would be act as a service provider.  Therefore you can find only the provisioning related configuration from there.  Also,  i guess,  [this](http://soasecurity.org/2014/10/03/in-boundout-bound-provisioning-with-identity-server/) may be help to understand the in-bound/out-bound provisioning with WSO2IS much better manner.